# document.activeElement.name not geting in safari for radiobutton

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

How can i get `document.activeElement.name` for radio button in safari. `document.activeElement.name` working fine in chrome and FF but its returns undefined in safari

Comment: check what is the `document.activeElement` on Safari, i guess not the expected one. Anyway, you have to provide minimalistic sample to replicate your issue

Comment: yes.. its not the expected one

Comment: so what is it? `body`, `label`, or what??? You have to be a little more versatile if you want some help... And btw, you still didn't provided any sample to replicate issue... When you go to the doctor, are you just telling him than you are sick?!

Comment: @A.Wolff :-) when i tried document.activeElement,it  gives '[object HTMLBodyElement]', and when  i tried document.activeElement.tagName it gives correct result in safari and FF as 'radio'.